# How to represent sentence with numerical value?

Tags: string, similarity, numerical, sentence

How can we represent a sentence using a unique numerical value, such that the similar sentences must have nearest value.

Example . sentence1== Smith visit LA. 
          sentence2== john visit California.

for these two sentence 1 & 2, their numerical value must be nearer to represent these two sentences contains similar message.

Comment: Need more info - For instance what programming language are you using? Are you trying to take a user-input sentence and compare it against the closest matches you have stored somewhere? IE if someone enters 'alan visit california' that will be nearer to 'john visit california' and thus return sentence2..?

Comment: A number is too simple data structure to be able to capture a complexity of human language sentences. Can't be done.

Comment: @Nealio ... i am using java. we have streaming sentences, none predefined sentences. we have to decide both sentences are similar by their numerical values, without considering each other sentences.

Comment: @Amadan .. huge size of numerical value such as 128 bit will be capable to represent the sentences.

Comment: @RameshKarn: There's about 180000 words in use in English language ([source](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language)). That's 18 bits. So, 128 bits give you enough space for *seven words* (if you ignore distributional restrictions). Not what I'd call huge. But my main complaint is not the size, but the structure: sentences are multidimensional, while numbers are one-dimensional. "John hit Jack", "Jill kissed Jack" and "Jill hit Lily" are (in a certain metrics) equidistant from "Jill hit Jack"; there can be at most 2 numbers equidistant from some X.

Comment: @RameshKarn: Then there's grammar: "Jack hit John" is more similar to "John was hit by Jack" than to "Jack kissed John". And then there's pragmatics, which says "Elvis is dead" and "The King has kicked the bucket" mean the same thing (while "The Queen has kicked the habit" means something very different, while being superficially similar). Saying "128 bit [is] capable to represent sentences" reveals a painful unfamiliarity with linguistics and language.

Comment: @Amadan .. Thanks for clarify these probable scenarios. But as i mentioned earlier i am trying to find the pattern for log messages and they may not contain these different representation for same message as you mention above. i heard about "locality sensitivity hashing" but having problem to use it.

Comment: @RameshKarn: If you want to find patterns in log messages, then *ask about log messages*. Preferably with some examples.

Comment: @Amadan ... ya, it should be nice 

here is some example of log messages

Oct  4 18:26:50  stm[1454]: <400166> <DBUG> |stm|  Received Stats Update for bssid 00:24:6c:ff:95:f0 wired mac 00:24:6c:c7:f9:5f phy_type is 1 

Oct  4 18:26:51  stm[1454]: <400166> <DBUG> |stm|  Received Stats Update for bssid 00:24:6c:3a:4f:e0 wired mac 00:24:6c:cb:a4:fe phy_type is 1 
Oct  4 18:26:51  stm[1454]: <400166> <DBUG> |stm|  Received Stats Update for bssid 00:24:6c:ff:a0:e0 wired mac 00:24:6c:c7:fa:0e phy_type is 1

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about understanding semantics of the sentence, [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and is not a trival task.  Unless your sentence data follows a **very** [rigid structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) and [similar patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_grammar); I think what you are asking is perhaps beyond the current state of the art and certainly at the level of PhD level research.

The only approach I can think would be to use natural language [compression](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/Dictionary_compression) using a known dictionary that has been mapped onto a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) that was semantically aware.

You could then evaluate how far each sentence (a path was on the graph) was from another and assign a cumlative weight.

Comment: its our bachelor project, Actually we are working on log messages, so applying NLP is little difficult in this case, because normally log message contains more distract structures.